# Array of fraction structures

Tags: c++, struct

I am working on a school assignment and one part of it has me a little stuck.  I need to have the user enter as many fractions as desired until a 0 is entered for the numerator, and save those fractions in a structure I created.

I was attempting to us strtok to split the c-string that I would use to store the user input by space and then by "/", but I got very stuck and couldn't get any proper output (the code below is main() it has a run time error and the second for loop would obviously fail in assigning anything proper to den).

What would be the simplest way in achieving this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct Fraction 
{
    int num, den;
};
int main()
{
    Fraction* fractions[100];
    char s[100] ;
    cout << "Enter fractions (end by entering a 0): ";
    cin >> s;
    const char* p;
    int count = 0;

    for (p = strtok( s, " " );  p;  p = strtok( NULL, "," ))
    {
        const char* frac = p;
        for (frac = strtok( s, " " );  frac;  frac = strtok( NULL, "/" ))
        {
            fractions[count]->num = (int)frac;
        count++;    
        }
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using `cin` so there would no `" "` in s.

Comment: You have an array of pointers, but you do not allocate memory for those pointers before accessing them. That leads to _undefined behaviour_. Stop using pointers when it's not needed, and stop using arrays when you have [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want

```
Fraction* fractions[100];
```

you just want

```
Fraction fractions[100];
```

The first is an array of *pointers* to `Fractions`s, the second is just an array of `Fractions`. The problem you are probably having is that you didn't initialize the pointers.

An even better approach might be to use a `std::vector<Fraction>` to store your `Fraction`s. Then, you can dynamically add to it, and it can store as many `Fraction`s as you need.

---

Another error you have is the way that you are reading in values. When you call

```
cin >> s;
```

It won't read in a full line, only a single token. Also, you're only ever setting the numerator of your fractions. Thus, you have two options:

1. Use `getline`, to read in a full line and then parse it from there.
2. Just use `cin >>` more effectively, and do something like:

-

```
while (cin >> s)
{
    char* frac = s;

    if (!strcmp(s, "0")) break;

    char* num = strtok( frac, "/" );
    char* denom = strtok( NULL, "/");

    fractions[count].num = atoi(num);
    fractions[count].den = atoi(denom);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The **first (runtime) error** is because of
`Fraction* fractions[100];`

This is an array of pointers to Fraction objects. But the Fraction objects themselves are never created/initialised.

This causes your segmentation fault at `fractions[count]->num = (int)frac;`

You can fix this a number of ways.
**1.**
`Fraction fractions[100];` as suggested by the other answer.
Simplest. Only other change would be to change the `->` to `.` in `fractions[count]->num = (int)frac;`

If you want to be efficient and create only as many objects as needed, then there are 2 ways of going about it.
**2 a.**
`Fraction* fractions[100] = null;`
`fractions[count] = new Fraction(atoi(frac));`
You are allocating on the heap and thus need to `delete` each object that you use when you are done

**2 b.**
`std::vector<Fraction> fractions;`
`fractions.push_back(Fraction(atoi(frac)));`
The more C++ -ish choice. [Vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) is (simplistically) an array that automatically becomes bigger as needed and thus doesnt need the max size upfront. Since you are making an vector of objects, you also do not need to `delete` them.

---

Your **second** error is `(int)frac;`. I believe you want `atoi(frac)`. The former would give you the pointer address of the character, which you dont want, while the latter would correctly parse the string into a number

---

I think you dont need an inner loop (for basic fractions). Just the below should do. Assuming that the user enters in the format `,<space><num>/<den><space>,`. Otherwise careful with the  use of strtok, since it modifies the input string. **That** might even be the issue with your code.. (edit) just to be safe, removed the nested strtok call.

```
fractions.push_back(Fraction(atoi(strtok(NULL,"/"),atoi(strtok(NULL," "))))
```

**Edit**
@Xymostech's input code is much cleaner, and also fixes the misunderstanding with the functioning of `cin`. You can just follow his version.

Comment: @Kathik T All your suggestions are great (and I voted up your answer), that get rid of the errors in my code.  However, this doesn't answer my question.  I am still failing to enter the users input into the array of structs properly. :)

Comment: check the 2nd error, thats part of your problem. Let me look again meanwhile